# Numpy Resize Image

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like to take an image and change the scale of the image, while it is a numpy array.
I would like to do it with **native NumPy functions w/o PIL, cv2, SciPy etc**

now I have this:

```
from copy import copy
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc


img = misc.face()  # racoon from SciPy(np.ndarray)
img2 = copy(img)  # copy of racoon, because misc.face() is Descriptor(?)
img2.shape()  # (768, 1024, 3)
```

Which I need shape = (3072, 4096, 3)

I can do it easy with Pillow

```
CONVERT_IMAGE = Image.fromarray(img.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
CONVERT_IMAGE = CONVERT_IMAGE.resize((4096, 3072), Image.NEAREST)

IMAGE_AS_ARRAY = np.asarray(CONVERT_IMAGE)
IMAGE_AS_ARRAY.shape  # 3072 4096 3
```

but I realy need to do this **only with NumPy functions** w/o other libs

Can you help me ? I'm really weak in NumPy and 3D-arrays

Comment: `numpy` doesn't do that kind of resizing.   It requires some sort of interpolation, which image libraries have developed.

Comment: @hpauji tnx for ur anwer, but i find downgrade of image size in numpy in some resources in Internet. But I cant find anywhere expand of image size

Comment: You can slice out a subset of the values, or as the answer shows replicate values.  But image software can do more sophisticated resizing - averaging values, smoothing the image and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limited to whole integer upscaling with some scaling factor `n` and without actual interpolation, you could use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) twice to get the described result:

```py
import numpy as np

# Original image with shape (4, 3, 3)
img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (4, 3, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Scaling factor for whole integer upscaling
n = 4

# Actual upscaling (results to some image with shape (16, 12, 3)
img_up = np.repeat(np.repeat(img, n, axis=0), n, axis=1)

# Outputs
print(img[:, :, 1], '\n')
print(img_up[:, :, 1])
```

Here's some output:

```
[[148 242 171]
 [247  40 152]
 [151 131 198]
 [ 23 185 144]] 

[[148 148 148 148 242 242 242 242 171 171 171 171]
 [148 148 148 148 242 242 242 242 171 171 171 171]
 [148 148 148 148 242 242 242 242 171 171 171 171]
 [148 148 148 148 242 242 242 242 171 171 171 171]
 [247 247 247 247  40  40  40  40 152 152 152 152]
 [247 247 247 247  40  40  40  40 152 152 152 152]
 [247 247 247 247  40  40  40  40 152 152 152 152]
 [247 247 247 247  40  40  40  40 152 152 152 152]
 [151 151 151 151 131 131 131 131 198 198 198 198]
 [151 151 151 151 131 131 131 131 198 198 198 198]
 [151 151 151 151 131 131 131 131 198 198 198 198]
 [151 151 151 151 131 131 131 131 198 198 198 198]
 [ 23  23  23  23 185 185 185 185 144 144 144 144]
 [ 23  23  23  23 185 185 185 185 144 144 144 144]
 [ 23  23  23  23 185 185 185 185 144 144 144 144]
 [ 23  23  23  23 185 185 185 185 144 144 144 144]]
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:     Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:       3.8.5
NumPy:        1.19.2
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: No Hans, I can't do this. third massive is RGB color and length of third massive is must be three, don't 12. Thanks for ur answer

Comment: Third dimension is still `3` in my solution!? You upscale from `(768, 1024, 3)` to `(3072, 4096, 3)`, which I also do, if I would start at `(768, 1024, 3)`. Also, please pay attention, I just output one channel of the final result - for readibility.

Comment: this is nearest-neighbor right?